# Assigning weights to indicators using pca

Tags: pca, stata

i am creating an index using stata consisting of 11 indicators. i want to assign weights to these indicators using PCA. i have checked correlation of the indicators and then ran the pca and performed rotation of the factors. however i am unsure as to how to calculate the final weights. i am new to this, and any help would be appreciated. thank you[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I really like a CUR decomposition for this kinda task, such as the importance values from this one: https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.0803205106

Comment: I never heard of this method. will definitely give it a look. thanks